# Kubuntu installer crashes

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 16.04.1 on my acer laptop (256 gb ssd, 1 tb hdd, 16 gb ram). All of the guided partition builds only use one of the disks so I attempted to do the manual. This is my first hdd/ssd pc so I don't expect that I did this well. I just put this together after reading the other similar posts about the install here.

```
 sda 
 - /         20 gb
 - /usr       7 gb
 - /usr/local 7 gb
 - /opt       5 gb
```

and on the hdd

```
sdb
 - /boot    350 mb
 - /home    10  gb
 - /var      5  gb 
 - /tmp     500 mb
```

But the installer crashed over and over again. I left the partitions as they were but didn't name them and it loaded, but once it restarted I removed the usb and reset the bios to factory settings and now it is saying there is no bootable device.

Any thoughts to what I could be doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Do you have (or plan to have) another operating system on the machine? Also, is this a recent laptop? What model is it?

Comment: It's about a year old. Acer aspire v 15 nitro. I was planning on also installing opensuse.

Comment: Ok. No Windows then? I think you are creating *way too many* partitions, and that they are way too small. I may write a detailed answer tomorrow, unless others chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar situation when installing to an single hard disk, I reset the BIOS after installing. I figured out a solution by looking at the settings and remembered that I had the legacy option on during the install, but was off after. After switching it on again, I rebooted and ouila! It worked. I changed the setting back and reinstalled it in UEFI mode, and that also worked after reboot. But in this case, I think you have to set the boot disk properly, among puting /boot (or have no /boot partition) on the ssd you don't need so many partitions, and should really have only 2, / on  the ssd and /home on the HDD.